# Not indexing properly on publish

Tags: solr, computed-field

I have a sitecore instance running on Sitecore v8.2 update 1 using SOLR. So I have created 3 new computed fields, this fields are working properly when I rebuild index or re-index tree (both master and web) but when I publish those computed field are removed from the web_index but stays on master_index.

Looking at the **OnPublishEndAsync** I don't seem to have any problem on the configration as I checked in [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/index-update-strategies.html). I also tried updating another field from the same computedindexconfiguration and it is updating properly on publish.

Is there any other configuration that I should look for when it comes to reindex on publish? Thanks in advance!

Updated with code

```
public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
{
    var indexableItem = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;
    if (indexableItem == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!indexableItem.Item.ID.IsNull && !indexableItem.Item.TemplateID.IsNull)
    {
        try
        {

            var item = indexableItem.Item;

            var categories = GetCategories(item.Database);

            if (categories  == null || categories.Categories == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            foreach (var category in categories.Categories)
            {
                if (category.Filter_By == Constants.Category.MetadataCategory)
                {
                    var itemCategory = item[Constants.Category.Category];

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemCategory))
                        continue;

                    var itemCategoryId = new ID(itemCategory).ToShortID().ToString().ToLower();
                    var matadataCategoryId = new ID(category.MetadataCategory).ToShortID().ToString().ToLower();
                    if(itemCategoryId = matadataCategoryId)
                    {
                        return matadataCategoryId;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Category > ComputeFieldValue : ", ex, "Category");
        }
    }

    return false;
}


public ICategoryFolder GetCategories(Database itemDatabase)
{
    var sitecoreService = new SitecoreService(itemDatabase);
    var sitecoreContextService = new SitecoreContextService();
    string categoriesFolderID = sitecoreContextService.GetAppSetting("CategoriesFolderID", "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}");
    Item categoriesFolder = ItemUtil.GetItemByItemId(categoriesFolderID, sitecoreService.Database);
    var categories = sitecoreService.CreateType<ICategoryFolder>(categoriesFolder);
    return categories;
}
```

Comment: I guess your computed field depends on some context information, am I right? Sitecore.Context or HttpContext? It's not present or it's not valid when reindexing in background after publishing

Comment: As @MarekMusielak mentioned, it would be helpful to add the code for your computed field.

Comment: Is this on single instance or CD/CM configuration?

Comment: @Marek I'm using the var indexableItem = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;, I get database from this item. Is that present when reindexing? 

It is in CD/CM configuration

I'll add that this works on my development instance which is on single instance configuration. But not working on the test environment that is in CD/CM configuration

Comment: Paste the whole code of your computed field

Comment: @MarekMusielak edited the post with code

Comment: I believe the problem is with using `SitecoreContextService` in `GetCategories` method. Try to get the values directly from settings/Sitecore without `SitecoreContextService`

Comment: @Jay Just a check - As this is a computed field, you must have applied the patch config file to add this computed field. Please check this patch is added correctly? Check the role where you have applied this patch. Whether it is Standalone, Content Management and Content Delivery.